# Wrong password stored when resetting it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to implement the feature where the users can reset their password when they forget it.

**Here is how it works :**

1. send email of account to `/user/forget-password` and get a 6 digit code
2. send reset code + new password to `/user/reset-password/:userId` and get a message of success
3. log in with email and new password

Until step 2, I have no errors and get the message:

> "Password updated successfully".

When I try to log in with the new password I get error:

> "message":"Invalid password."

**What I did:**

So I created these routes:

```
router.post("/login", authController.signIn);

router.post("/forget-password", authController.forgetPassword);
router.post("/reset-password/:userId", authController.resetPasword);
```

and controllers :

```
module.exports.signIn = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "User not found.",
    });
  }


  const isValidPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

  if (!isValidPassword) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "Invalid password.",
      error: res.error
    });
  }

  const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
    expiresIn: "2h",
  });

  res.status(200).json({
    message: "User logged in.",
    token,
    user: {
      id: user._id,
      email: user.email,
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName: user.lastName,
    },
  });
};

module.exports.forgetPassword = async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  const resetCode = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000).toString();

  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({ email }, { resetCode });

    if (!user) return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });

    res.json({ message: "Reset code generated", userId: user._id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error" });
  }
};

module.exports.resetPasword = async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;
  const { resetCode, newPassword } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findById(userId);

    if (!user) return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });

    if (user.resetCode !== resetCode) return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid reset code" });

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const newHashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt);

    user.password = newHashedPassword;
    user.resetCode = null;

    await user.save();

    res.json({ message: "Password updated successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error" });
  }
};
```

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Provide an email."],
    unique: true,
    match: [
      /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/,
      "Please, provide a valid email.",
    ],
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Password is required."],
  },
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Firstname is required."],
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Lastname is required."],
  },
  resetCode: {
    type: String,
    default: null,
  }
});

UserSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  const user = this;
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
  user.password = hash;
  next();
});

UserSchema.methods.isValidPassword = async function (password) {
  const user = this;
  const compare = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

  return compare;
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

In MongoDB collection I can see that the hash password has changed, so it means the new password is stored (yes ?)

Does someone see where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you add UserModel code?

Comment: You are hashing the password both in model and in routes.